# TFS 2013 Build machine lost connectivity to message queue

Tags: tfs, msbuild

TFS build controller is outputting the following error message when starting up:

```
Build machine [BuildServerName] lost connectivity to message queue tfsmq://buildservicehost-5/.
Reason: Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
  HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
```

I've tried recreating the build controller and re-registering the build service.

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot the tfsmq or have an existing solution to the error I'm receiving? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation I found the true cause of the problem on the TFS server itself:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/62476613
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (1045856256 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.. ---> System.InsufficientMemoryException: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (1045856256 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceMemoryGates.Check(Int32 minFreeMemoryPercentage, Boolean throwOnLowMemory, UInt64& availableMemoryBytes)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CheckMemoryCloseIdleServices(EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 6404
```

The issue as you can see above was that the server was running low on memory (less than 5% free memory). We currently have SQL server living on the same server as TFS. Due to the incredibly large size of the databases the SQL server had chewed up all of the available memory on the box.

The issue was fixed by reducing the maximum allocated memory of the SQL server to allow for TFS.

If anyone is interested this was done by:

1. Opening SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Right clicking on the server instance; select properties.
3. Select the "Memory" page.
4. Enter a reasonable value in the "Maximum server memory" property.

Comment: Where did you find that exception message? Event Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

For us, it was the IIS App Pool on the TFS Admin Server ( "Microsoft Team Foundation Server Message Queue Application Pool" ) was stopped.

Comment: I also had a problem with the App Pool stopped, Thanks Tom Fort

Comment: Same issue encountered lately - recycle of the IIS App Pool fixed the issue